# Why are functions assigned to variables in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Simple question about syntax. In Angular, I've seen functions inside a controller created like this:

```
this.multiply = function multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b; 
}
```

I'm a bit thrown of since the function is given a name and also assigned to a variable with. So my question is why are functions assigned to variables in Angular? Does this affect scope?

Comment: it just makes them publicly accessible to whoever has an instance to the controller.

Comment: Why the down votes ? It's a valid question.

Comment: More commonly you'll create something on scope in the viewmodel (controller) so your view has access to it (e.g. a click handler).

Comment: @DanielA.White, if you post your comment as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: To the people that keep down-voting, it would be helpful if you could illuminate what your problem with the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't assigning it to a variable. It is assigning it to the instance of the controller, with `this`; so whoever has an instance of the controller can call it.

Answer (score 3):

This is standard JavaScript and this is called [Named function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).

By using `this` you are defining it on controller. If you use `controlleras` syntax in views or while defining routes you can use such functions as well as any properties defined on `this`.

Earlier versions of Angular only employed `$scope` and everything had to be defined on `$scope`.

Now the controller itself is instantiated on scope depending upon controller name alias in `controlleras`